# why scanf skips '\n' in freopen function?

Tags: c, scanf, freopen

I'm using **freopen** function to read files. But when i use **scanf** statement to scan integers, it skips '\n' character. How can i avoid skipping **'\n'** by scanf.

Comment: By default, scanf for an integer will skip all whitespace characters ('\n' being one of them) until the next integer. If you want to read until end-of-line, consider using gets/fgets instead of scanf.

Comment: What do you mean by "skips '\n'"? It's better to show some code for detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't! But don't worry, there are workarounds.

Workaround:

Read input one line at a time (using fgets) and then use `sscanf` to scan for integers.

```
#define LINE_MAX 1000
line[LINE_MAX];
int num;

while (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fp) != NULL) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &num) == 1) {
        // Integer scanned successfully
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend posting more of your coding goal so we may suggest how to avoid the need to “not skip \n”.

`scanf()` does not skip `'\n'`.  Select format specifies like `"%d"` direct `scanf()` to skip leading white-pace – including `'\n'`.

If one wants to use `scanf()` and not skip `'\n'`, use format specifiers like `"%[]"` or `"%c"`.  Alternatively, try a new approach with `fgets()` or `fgetc()`.

If code *must* use `scanf()` and not skip leading `'\n'` when scanning an `int`, suggest the following:

```
char buf[100];
int cnt = scanf("%99[-+0123456789 ]", buf);
if (cnt != 1) Handle_UnexpectedInput(cnt);

// scanf the buffer using sscanf() or strtol()
int number;
char sentinel
cnt = sscanf(buf, "%d%c", &number, &sentinel);
if (cnt != 1) Handle_UnexpectedInput(cnt);
```

Alternative: consume all leading whitespace first, looking for `\n`.

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && isspace(ch));
ungetc(ch, stdin);
if (ch == '\n') Handle_EOLchar();
int number;
int cnt = scanf("%d", &number);
if (cnt != 1) Handle_FormatError(cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

`xscanf` functions will process the strings by DFA. It will search the format which is given by *fmt* argument, each space chars(space,\t,\n,\r etc.) will be skipped. You can insert these *space chars* to *fmt* for matching.

For example, how it does skipping:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* s = "1 2 \n 3 4 \n 5 \n \n \n 6";
    int i,c;
    int tot=0;
    while(sscanf(s+tot,"%d%n",&i,&c)){
        printf("'%s':%d,cnt=%d\n",s+tot,i,c);
        tot += c;
    }
    return 0;
}
/*** Output:
'1 2 
 3 4 
 5 


 6':1,cnt=1
' 2 
 3 4 
 5 


 6':2,cnt=2
' 
 3 4 
 5 


 6':3,cnt=4
' 4 
 5 


 6':4,cnt=2
' 
 5 


 6':5,cnt=4
' 


 6':6,cnt=8
'':6,cnt=8
***/
```